# Opencv video codec OSX

Tags: macos, opencv, codec

I'm working through the example in openCV Highgui that can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-input-psnr-ssim/video-input-psnr-ssim.html#videoinputpsnrmssim%5d). It may be worth noting that i'm running osx. When running the file I get the error "WARNING: Couldn't read movie file video/Megamind.avi" . Is this a codec problem (the .avi file came with openCV) or an environment problem? How is this fixed?

Comment: depends what settings you've used when you built opencv. For example I use ffmpeg, QtKit, V4L but no Quicktime. having highgui built with ffmpeg should work.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I ran into problems installing yasm in order to get ffmpeg to install. I installed it with homebrew on separate machines and got the same linking error. I'm gonna try [this](http://www.cvlibs.net/projects/ffmpeg_opencv.html) next or [this one](http://tech.enekochan.com/2012/07/27/install-opencv-2-4-2-with-ffmpeg-support-in-mac-os-x-10-8/)

Comment: That should work. I usually do: `sudo port install ffmpeg` then when I build from source I use ccmake to configure the ffmpeg option for OpenCV (e.g. in the OpenCV source directory: `mkdir build && cd build && ccmake..` - then press `c`, scroll though options, enable ffmpeg, press `c` again then `g` to generate. All that's left is the usual `make` and `make install` afterwards)

Answer (score 1):

sometime  port install complains and screws up old installations.  Try brew OS X's package manager to install ffmpeg

Comment: Actually the brew package manager was broken for ffmpeg. Something about yasm wouldn't link. But I found a better way. I followed these directions http://tech.enekochan.com/2012/07/27/install-opencv-2-4-2-with-ffmpeg-support-in-mac-os-x-10-8/ to install opencv with ffmpeg and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Megamind.avi is in XVID. Try installing the XVID codec [from XVID](http://www.xvid.org/Downloads.43.0.html). I guess the OSX package manager can get it as well.

To answer your question more directly: I guess you could both build opencv with the right references but it worked for me (in Windows) just to setup the codec for my system in general.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instruction (See below) for installing opencv on mac os X with ffmpeg support.
It worked and I can see  my .avi files working.  There is a detail installation instruction,
step by step.

[follow this link](http://tech.enekochan.com/2012/07/27/install-opencv-2-4-2-with-ffmpeg-support-in-mac-os-x-10-8/)